# How to get XPATH Attributes quantity

Tags: xml, xpath

Is it possible to get quantity of attributes in node in XPATH? 
Like :

count(/entity-list/entity[@*]) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is the Location Path:

```
count(/entity-list/entity/@*)
```